# COUNTIF not counting text correctly when exact text has operator

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that is auto-generated from a database and I am trying to count the text `<None>` in the table. I am using the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(SomeTable[SomeColumn],"<None>")
```

It produces an incorrect count that is way off but I believe it is interpreting the < and > as an operator throwing off the count.

It counts appropriately when I change the < and > to *'s

```
=COUNTIF(SomeTable[SomeColumn],"*None*")
```

How do you make the formula interpret `<none>`as text only.

Comment: What are you looking for it to count? When the text is not "None"? `"<>None"` would to it. Can you kindly clarify your question? If the second formula works, why not just use that?

Comment: I want to search for "<None>" as this this what the database spits out.

Comment: The text <none> did not show on the original question due to how stack exchange interpreted it so I had to format it as Code in the question so it would show sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `=` in front:

```
=COUNTIF(SomeTable[SomeColumn],"=<None>")
```

The mathematical operands are `>=` or `<=` and not `=>` or `=<` So anything after the `=` is considered the value to count.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SomeTable[SomeColumn]="<None>")+0)
```

Thanks to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029970/excel-countif-function-treats-less-than-character-as-an-operator)

Comment: Thanks Bruce that does work but if I needed to use multiple criteria with a COUNTIFS that wouldn't help it looks like Scott answered what I was looking for.

Comment: @MatthewLozoya - I kind of figured he'd show up :)  ...glad you got it solved!